# path join not working in webpack5 but it is working with webpack4

Tags: webpack, webpack-4, webpack-5

After moving to webpack5 I get an error for this line (this was working with webpack4):

```
addPath: path.join(process.cwd(), 'public', MISSING_LOCALE_PATH),
```

and get the following error:

```
Unhandled Runtime Error
TypeError: path__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1___default(...).join is not a function
```

After changing to

```
addPath: `${process.cwd()}/public/${MISSING_LOCALE_PATH}`
```

it works

any idea how can I get path.join works in webpack5?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Webpack v5 removed automatic node.js pollyfills. See details [here](https://github.com/webpack/changelog-v5#automatic-nodejs-polyfills-removed) and [here](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/11282)